# jQuery function custom assambled callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

Something like:

```
var myFunction = 'hello';    
$(".someElement").click(application.controller. + myFunction);
```

or

```
var myFunction = application.controller + '.hello';    
$(".someElement").click(myFunction);
```

So it should open application.controller.hello();

Any ideas? Cuz aboves isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
var myFunction = 'hello';    
$(".someElement").click(application.controller[myFunction])
```

Comment: Or indeed `var myFunction = application.controller['hello']; $(".someElement").click(myFunction)`, which is closer to what the OP was attempting but is essentially the same.